# Apache Spark 2.3.1 - is pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport() necessary?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

My understanding of Hive is that it provides a way to query a HDFS with SQL commands.

Okay but then there's Spark. Spark has all of it's RDD class methods, which are totally capable, but I'm more comfortable with SQL.

Enter Spark SQL. So now that I can query my db with SQL using Spark SQL, why does Hive enter the picture?

docs say :

```
enableHiveSupport():
Enables Hive support, including connectivity to a persistent Hive metastore, support for Hive serdes, and Hive user-defined functions.
```

Why would you need to connect to a Hive metastore?
In the docs for spark, it says to configure hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml and to set `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh` to a location containing the configuration files.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#inheriting-hadoop-cluster-configuration

Note: this is kinda my first time simply reading docs and trying to grok what's going on... apache is interesting.

Can someone just confirm that I can forget about HIVE?

Answer (score 1):

spark-shell has this automatically. In a compiled spark-submit you need Hive support to access and update hive metastore or Spark metastore. Question of protocol. For jdbc usage for db access it is not needed. If writing files only then also not needed, e.g. Parquet write or append to an HDFS subdirectory. But then you cannot use spark.sql... against a Hive table, Impala table, as it is a file only. Kudu a little different if wanting to go through Impala jdbc.